# How to do windows API calls in Python 3.1?

Tags: python, winapi, python-3.x

Has anyone found a version of [pywin32](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/) for python 3.x? The latest available appears to be for 2.6.

Alternatively, how would I "roll my own" windows API calls in Python 3.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are pywin32 available for 3.0. Python 3.1 was release two days ago, so if you need pywin32 for that you either need to wait a bit, or compile them from source.

http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=78018&package_id=79063

Comment: Ah I see! It seems I fail at reading comprehension ("This project is now being hosted at sourceforge - there may be later versions available than referenced on this page")

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to do everything with [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html), if a bit cumbersomely.

Here's an example of getting the "common application data" folder:

```
from ctypes import windll, wintypes

_SHGetFolderPath = windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW
path_buf = wintypes.create_unicode_buffer(255)
csidl = 35
_SHGetFolderPath(0, csidl, 0, 0, path_buf)
print(path_buf.value)
```

Result:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
```

Comment: Cool! I will have a play with that too.